# Doing char32_t c = U'\x00000010'; with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

The code `char32_t c = U'\xffffffff';` works with GCC but not with Visual Studio 2013. What is the solution to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
uint32_t c = '\Uffffffff';
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6aw8xdf2.aspx

Comment: GCC complains: "main.cpp:8:18: error: \Uffffffff is not a valid universal character".

Comment: timrau already mentioned a solution. Such an integer codepoint can easily be expressed with `0xffffffff`. To have always the right type (such an int constant may well be 64bits), one can either do `UINT32_C(0xffffffff)` or `~UINT32_C(0)`

Answer (score 3):

char32_t and string literals are not yet supported:
See the documenation.

see MSDN here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the value as an integer rather than a character literal:

```
char32_t c = 0xffffffff;
```